# Is it possible to get past Google's "Our systems have detected unusual traffic" page in a text-only browser?

Tags: elinks

I like using a text-only browser (elinks) to do basic web-browsing. Unfortunately, I recently keep getting Google's "Our systems have detected unusual traffic" page, which offers a CAPTCHA to let me continue, which of course I can't view.

Is there any way to continue past this?

Comment: http://startpage.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down to the bottom of something like gmail, on the bottom right is a link called "Details"
At the bottom of the window that pops up is an Alert Preference that asks to Show an alert for unusual activity or to never show an alert for unusual activity.

I would suggest starting there.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of possibilities  of why you are seeing that page.

1) You are behind a proxy
2) Your browser is not sending the right useragent which could make it look like a bot/bot net
3) On a shared large network

Comment: Since I'm connected via SSH to my server at a large hosting provider, it's (3) of course, shame that there's nothing I can do about it...

Comment: Google does not expect the hosting provider of doing browser searches, and assumes you are not human, but provides the captcha to temporary say you are human.  I have done the same, ssh tunnel and have same problem.